# Take SQL database online/offline using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there any way to take sql db online/offline programmatically using C#? I also noticed while database is offline, my C# program throws login failed exception.

my code:

```
var conn = CCULBCommon.Connection.connection("master");
            conn.Open();
            var sqlCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"ALTER DATABASE {0} SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", dbName);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: I suspect you are trying to connect to the database you are taking offline - you should connect to the *master* database instead.

Comment: you might want to explain what you're trying to achieve and why

Comment: Risky move, the database engine may have set it offline because of a good reason. Personally I would not automate bringing the database online without human intervention (database admin should check what was going on)

Comment: You forgot sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: You also forgot `using` on your connection and command objects, and you should ensure your database name is correctly escaped

Answer (score 6):

You can, there are 2 options

1. Connect to the master database and do `ALTER DATABASE [DbName] SET ONLINE` or `ALTER DATABASE [DbName] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`
2. You can use [SqlManagmentObjects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects) and setup a connection with SMO and then you can use [SetOffline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.setoffline?view=sql-smo-160) or [SetOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.setonline?view=sql-smo-160). See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/create-program/connecting-to-an-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-to-an-instance-of-sql-server-by-using-sql-server-authentication-in-visual-c) on how to connect with SMO.

Comment: I have tried by connecting to master db, but it's not going to offline. There are no errors. My code is given in question. Can you please tell what's wrong with it?

Comment: _not working_ doesn't mean anything. Please don't post that. Why is it not working? an error?

Comment: there is no error

Comment: @TafsirAhamed Your SQL statement is NEVER executed. You create it but you don't actually do anything with it.

Comment: _there is no error_... so you run your code and the outcome is not what you expected? As per many posts on this question already - you are not actually executing anything